# svn import to current directory (without file:/// or http:///)

Tags: batch-file, svn, import, directory

I am creating a batch file that create a repository and will import a folder from an existing and fixed directory into that repository.

**The repository will be created in the folder in which the batch file is placed in**. So for example, if a user decides to place the batch file in the directory called C:/temp and runs the batch file, the repository will be created and placed in C:/temp. If the batch file is placed in C:/foo, the repository will be created and placed in C:/foo.

To do this, the batch file has this command:

```css
svnadmin create ./Module_QWER
```

In the batch file however, there is a problem when using "svn import". I tried to import a folder from a directory into the repository that was just created by doing this:

```css
svn import "C:/temp/content to import" ./Module_QWER/Sample/Trunk
```

And an error occurs:

```css
svn: E205000: Try 'svn help import' for more information
svn: E205000: Invalid URL 'Module_QWER/Sample/Trunk'
```

I understand that if the URL of the repository is in full the import will work, but as said before the URL of the repository will depend on where the user puts the batch file. Is there a way to import the folder into a repository no matter where the repository is placed as long as it is placed together in the same directory as the batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use svn commands related to a specific repository, you need to have its full path and the protocol you are connecting with.
So the path to the repository should be something like:

```
file:///d:/full/path/to/repo
```

In your case it would be:

```
svn import "C:/temp/content to import" file:///%cd%/Module_QWER/Sample/Trunk -m "log message"
```

Edit: *OK, I just noticed the title of the question is without using the protocol in the path.
I don't think it's possible, but full path to the repository can simply be achieved with using `%~dp0%` for the batch's current directory or `%cd%` for the current working directory.*

Comment: Thank you so much! I used this at the end instead though:

Comment: file:///%~dp0%/Module_QWER/Sample/Trunk

Comment: @DanielleXin  Glad I could help.